# How to use autoscroll in Angular UI-ROUTER

Tags: angular-ui-router

All:

I am pretty new to Angular UI-Router, when I come to ui-view, there is one attribute called "autoscroll" confused me so much, I thought it controll if the view page scroll(**is my understanding correct, if not, please help with what this autoscroll does**), but when I use it like:

```
<body ng-controller="main">
    <div class="header">
        <span>
            <a ui-sref="home">HOME</a>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a ui-sref="signup">SIGNUP</a>
        </span>     
    </div>
    <div class="body" ui-view autoscroll=false statename={{scroll}}></div>
</body>
```

And

```
app
.controller("main", function($scope){
    $scope.scroll = true;
})
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
        .state("signup", {
            url: "/signup",
            template: "<div class='signup'><span>This  is a signup page. </span><p>And a long paragraph is follow</span></div>"
        })
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            template: "<div class='home'><span>This is a home page.  </span><span>And a long paragraph is follow</span></div>"
        })

})
```

I have tried

```
autoscroll=false
autoscroll=true
autoscroll="false"
autoscroll="true"
//I set $scope.scroll to true and false
autoscroll={{scroll}}
autoscroll=scroll
autoscroll="scroll"
```

None of these works: when I scroll current view down and switch to another view, it always automatically scroll to Top, **what I want is keep the view to current scroll position**, any idea?

Thanks for help.